# Is there a link which shows related questions?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, related-questions

For any post I can obtain list of linked questions by using `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/id` here id is the number of question. The advantage of this version, compared to the version in the sidebar, is that I see also preview of the body, not only the title of each question in the list.

Examples:

- This post has many linked questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/59445
- The post I just made does not have any linked questions at the moment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/258943

> Is there something similar for related questions

Of course, I have tried simply to replace the word linked by the word related in the url, but that does not work (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/related/59445, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/related/258943).